# cacheGroups discards my groups and only creates first two groups

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

I want to split my bundle into chunks according to below scheme. However, Only first 2 chunk group is considered and my `editor` group inserted to my application main js (`app`) instead of separate chunk.

### Expected Result:

```
    "/packs/js/runtime~app.js",
    "/packs/js/vendors.chunk.js",
    "/packs/js/app-commons.chunk.js",
    "/packs/js/editors.chunk.js", // Editors are in this.
    "/packs/js/app.chunk.js"
```

### Actual Result:

```
    "/packs/js/runtime~app.js",
    "/packs/js/vendors.chunk.js",
    "/packs/js/app-commons.chunk.js",
    "/packs/js/app.chunk.js"  // instead, editors inserted to this...
```

It seems after `app-commons`, it just discard the rest. **But**, If I remove `app_commons` then `editors` get created as a chunk. It seems after second group it just doesn't respect on my rules.

### Code:

```
splitChunks(config =>
  Object.assign({}, config, {
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
          commons: {
            test(mod /* , chunk */) {
              if (!mod.context.includes('node_modules')) {
                return false
              }
              if (
                ['editor', 'draft-js', 'highlight'].some(str =>
                  mod.context.includes(str),
                )
              ) {
                return false
              }
              return true
            },
            name: 'vendors',
            chunks: 'all',
            reuseExistingChunk: true,
          },
          app_commons: {
            test(mod /* , chunk */) {
              if (!mod.context.includes('node_modules')) {
                return false
              }
              if (['draft-js', 'highlight'].some(str => mod.context.includes(str))) {
                return true
              }
              return false
            },
            name: 'app-commons',
            chunks: 'all',
            reuseExistingChunk: true,
          },
          editor: {
            test(mod /* , chunk */) {
              if (!mod.context.includes('node_modules')) {
                return false
              }
              if (['editor'].some(str => mod.context.includes(str))) {
                return true
              }
              return false
            },
            name: 'editors',
            chunks: 'all',
            reuseExistingChunk: true,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  }),
)
```

Comment: did you checked that you got the success (`return true`) branch? try to add `enforce: true` to your editor configuration.

Comment: Wow! `enforce: true` worked! Thank you!. You might write this as an answer so i can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add `enforce: true` to your editor configuration.